# Error 400 Bad request when I use PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

When I `CURL` in PHP. With appropriate headers and fields but It will give me error **Error 400 Bad request.** Why this error becomes?

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: close Content-Type: text/html
400 Bad request
Your browser sent an invalid request. 1
```

**Header Request**

```
$header[] = "Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
$header[]="Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate";
$header[] = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";
$header[]= "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Content-Length:37";
$header[]="Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
$header[]="Cookie:__qca=P0-116849880-1387336057175; __utma=140029553.335591273.1387336057.1389609300.1389617402.102; __utmz=140029553.1389617402.102.89.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _ga=GA1.2.335591273.1387336057; sgt=id=3380ce36-a139-4845-bd20-5bb3fd4174ec; usr=t=qrthm51g2UyV&s=QtuIYj84zEOR";
$header[]="X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest";
```

**CURL Code**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_, $value);
$response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If you want any further data please comment I will explain in detail.

Comment: Please show the request headers.

Comment: could you show us the actual code?

Comment: @Imat do you mean `http` or `https`? It's http

Comment: @Sadikhasan sometimes you need to use this. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); please check also if  the server you're requesting for is allowed to an access control origin.

Comment: Sorry! I have no luck

Answer (score 4):

A 400 response means that the HTTP server that the request went to has said that the request is invalid.

Why?

Who knows!  Maybe the URL you sent in the request has malformed arguments (in the query string) or maybe it requires arguments that you didn't supply.  Or maybe the problem is the other headers.

Or maybe it just doesn't like you.

I suggest that you compare the request you are sending with either the web site's API documentation or a request sent by a (real) browser.  And if that fails, ask the folks who look after the web server you are sending the requests to.